# What is Shikizaki Kiki's final completed Deviant Sword?

Tags: katanagatari

In the series, it was mentioned that Shikizaki Kiki created the 12 Deviant Swords with the purpose of perfecting one final sword.

What is this final sword? How was it completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In episode 11, Kiki Shikizaki said that the final purpose of the 12 Deviant Swords was to help Yasuri Shichika perfect the Kyotoryu fighting style in order to forge **himself** as the ultimate completed Deviant Sword (虚刀「鑢」; Empty Sword "File"). So Shichika himself is the final sword and forged through the Kyotoryu fighting style.

The other purpose of the creation of the swords is to prevent Japan from being destroyed by foreigners. Something that one of his ancestors told him would happen.